# Access seahorse passwords from terminal

Tags: security, seahorse

Like this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/514050/synchronise-passwords-across-devices-with-pass), I am looking for a password repository and that I can use to feed my programs and scripts with those passwords.

I found `seahorse` which seems to have what I need under the "Login" folder but I am not quite sure where the passwords are stored (for backup) and I don't know how to get the passwords in shell so I can pipe them into my scripts. I was under the impression that I can use `gpg` to access those passwords, but I don't quite know how.

Is it possible to access (and create) those passwords in terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seahorse is a GUI frontend to the Gnome keyring. The [libsecret library](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/) comes with a command line utility called [`secret-tool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/secret-tool.1.html) which lets you access the Gnome keyring from the command line or a script.

Examples of `secret-tool` usage: [for mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20570/mutt-how-to-safely-store-password/559397#559397), [for mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414614/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-from-a-shell-script-to-my-muttrc/414634#414634), [in a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279941/sudo-like-remembrance-of-passwords-for-own-scripts/280145#280145), [in a CentOS Docker container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473528/how-do-you-enable-the-secret-tool-command-backed-by-gnome-keyring-libsecret-an), [in a systemd unit file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391040/is-there-a-typical-way-to-pass-a-password-to-a-systemd-unit-file/511816#511816).

For backup purposes, [the keyring file is in `~/.local/share/keyrings`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96798/where-does-seahorse-gnome-keyring-store-its-keyrings).

Comment: Could you add an example on how to query passwords saved in seahorse with that tool? I cannot make it work ... [See also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470384/is-it-possible-to-use-secret-tool-to-lookup-existing-seahorse-passwords)

Comment: Okay, if you know an attribute and its full value you can query it, but it seems not possible to do a fuzzy/regex search for e.g. the label.

Comment: @pLumo `secret-tool search …`. But indeed I think you need to know at least one attribute. If you don't, I think the next most convenient tool is the Python API. I used it in the past [to automatically change passwords](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214126/change-the-password-for-many-accounts-at-once-in-gnome-keyring). Beware that the API isn't stable, I don't know if that script still works today.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' you might be delighted to learn about lssecret: https://askubuntu.com/a/1155765/207933

Comment: Would be nice to have an example to see how you could retrieve real stuff out of it. E.g. `secret-tool lookup signon_realm https://lwn.net/` (note that the value must be identical, I wasted a bit of time when avoided / at the end) will retrieve password for this site.